# Use BuddyPress data in loop (mkdir)

Tags: loop, buddypress

I am trying to create a folder per user based on BuddyPress fields, using the following:

```
bp_member_profile_data( 'field=ID Number' );
```

If I use the above code with mkdir, it doesn't work (ie, the folder name will just be "User - "   (with no ID Number)

This is my loop code:

```
<?php
if ( bp_has_members( 'per_page=0', bp_ajax_querystring( 'members' ) ) ) :
do_action( 'bp_before_directory_members_list' );

while ( bp_members() ) : bp_the_member(); ?>

$member = bp_member_profile_data( 'field=ID Number' );
mkdir("SiteUsers/User - " . $member ,0755, true );

endwhile; endif;
?>
```

I have no idea where I'm going wrong, if anyone could help me I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it doesn't work (ie, the folder name will just be "User - " (with no
> ID Number)

Did you check to see if and what `bp_member_profile_data( 'field=ID Number' );` returns as a value?  And that function will `echo` the value. To just return the value use `bp_get_member_profile_data( 'field=ID Number' );`

But... For God's sake... Why would you use a member loop to do that?

And what is `bp_member_profile_data( 'field=ID Number' );`
The member_id? Or some custom id you assign per member?  And if so, why?

For a one-time creation of such directories, I would do something like this, assuming you want a single directory for each user:

```
function create_user_dirs() {
 
    $users = get_users( array( 'fields' => 'ID' ) );

    $path = // put the absolute path to the existing 'SiteUsers' directory here

    foreach ( $users as $user_id )
        wp_mkdir_p( $path . '/' . $user_id );
      
}
```

If 'field=ID Number' is really different from the user_id, then do this:

```
foreach ( $users as $user_id ) {
    $id_number = xprofile_get_field_data( 'ID Number', $user_id, 'comma' );
    wp_mkdir_p( $path . '/' . $id_number );
}
```

Use [wp_mkdir_p](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mkdir_p)

I believe it sets permissions to 755 or whatever the parent dir is set to.

Comment: `bp_get_member_profile_data( 'field=ID Number' );` was the answer!! You saved my life!! :D I'm using the function for a FPDF function - not a once-off thing, that's why I'm using a loop. Anyways, it's working flawlessly now, thank you, thank you, thank you!!!!

Comment: You should also check to see if the dir already exists before attempting to create it. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php

Comment: Thank you for a great suggestion. And again for your awesome help :)